# Making a paypal subscribe button do an auto return

Tags: html, button, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I've reviewed all the discussions about Paypal buttons and auto-returning to a page of a website.  None of them seem to specifically address what I want to do...I apologize if I missed it though.  If I did, could someone direct me to it based on my question following?

I need a Paypal subscription button that overrides the website-wide auto-return setting.  I have that turned off, because I don't want ALL purchases to go this certain page, only the paypal subscribe button return I'm trying to create.  (If I left website-wide auto-return on, then every single transaction would go to that page, and I don't want that.)

So I need this subscription button to auto-return to a specific page, even though website-wide auto-return is off.

Of course, I did try turning on the selection in step 3 of button creation that says "Take customers to this URL when they check out", but that only shows them the button after Agree and Pay--the button that gives them a choice to return to the page, but I don't want them to get that choice.  I want the button to auto-return to the page, no matter what.

Any way to solidly code that into the form?
Help!
Shawn D.

Comment: You need to turn on the auto return and you can provide the return there also. If you specify the return url in button code that will overide the url specified in your PayPal account . So , as long as you are passing return url explicitly in your button code that will always be given precedence.